# PHP: Get element of an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an element stored in the following way:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["data"]. "</td></tr>";
    $data1= floatval($row["data"]);
    ...
```

It is a value extracted from a MySQL database, and thus it is stored this way. If I want to get the value of the iteration let's say "i", it is easy, as I do not have to do anything else but how can I obtain the following value in order to perform a substraction? That's to say, data2 - data1? I thought about something similar to $row["data"][i], but I'm not sure it'll work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the manual of [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) this function fetches only one row at a time and that's why we're using a loop.
The same goes for `fetch_array` and `fetch_row`.

> mysqli_result::fetch_assoc -- mysqli_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row
>   as an associative array

The only solution that I can think of is to loop that array and to store that data in another array according to your requirements, for instance:

```
$customArr = array();
$i = 0; //counter.
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["data"]. "</td></tr>";
    $data1= floatval($row["data"]);
    $customArr[$i] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'date' => $date1);
}
```

Later on, if you want to compare values in the array you should use `while` and index-based scenarios like `$customArr[$i-1]`, `$customArr[$i]`.
Just make sure that you check the offset.

```
$i = 0;
while($i < count($customArr)){

}
```

Comment: What is the utility of the ID field? Thanks.

Comment: I just added it as an example, you don't have to use it. But in case that you would like to mention that row's ID or a link to that item.